# Why does adduser prompt for a UNIX password instead of a Linux password

Tags: linux, unix

`user@li86-73 ~ $ sudo adduser myUser
Adding user 'myUser' ...
Adding new group 'myUser' (1001) ...
Adding new user 'myUser' (1001) with group 'myUser' ...
Creating home directory '/home/myUser' ...
Copying files from '/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:`

Why does the password prompt refer to UNIX and not Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is a (nearly) direct descendant of UNIX, and many of the utilities were written for the GNU software project to replace AT&T's licensed utilities in UNIX before Linux was even around.

Probably the Linux developers saw no need to change the string in the prompt.

Edited to add: Possibly more important, changing the prompt string would break any script running "adduser" that was looking for the standard prompt.